# JPA java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I have a JPQL query that generate that native query :

```
SELECT ID, MODALNAMES, NAME, NUMBER, TABLE_CONFIG_ID FROM TAB_CONF_TABS WHERE (TABLE_CONFIG_ID = ?)
```

what's wrong with it ? My db is Oracle.

This is a error that appears in the console:

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression

Error Code: 936
Call: SELECT ID, MODALNAMES, NAME, NUMBER, TABLE_CONFIG_ID FROM TAB_CONF_TABS WHERE (TABLE_CONFIG_ID = ?)
    bind => [25]
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="tabs" referenceClass=TabConfig sql="SELECT ID, MODALNAMES, NAME, NUMBER, TABLE_CONFIG_ID FROM TAB_CONF_TABS WHERE (TABLE_CONFIG_ID = ?)")
```

Comment: NUMBER is a reserved keyword

Comment: Where is the JPQL? and the entity? nobody can tell you "what is wrong with it" without basic info